# iOS - UIAutoresizingMask margin : why do I need to set both sides?

Tags: ios, autoresizingmask

My question may appear strange, but with an example it's easier to understand :

I have, let's say an UIButton, that I create and then :

```
// [...] Create button, add it to view
myButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

If I don't specify **UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin**, my component will not be at the right x-ratio on the screen. Why ? I specified left margin, so my element should be at the good position when I rotate the device... Don't understand the need of the right margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use both flexible margins, a change in width will be split between the two margins. This is commonly used to keep a view centered.

When you use just one flexible margin, a change in width will all be applied to the one flexible margin. This means the other margin stays the same, no matter how the width changes.

Comment: Still don't get it. If I have my button at 32px for my portrait UI. That's 10% left, right ? When I rotate and I set only the left margin, that's not 10% left at all for the landscape UI.

Comment: Ok, I didn't think the good way. As the right margin is not flexible, it will remain the same as the portrait UI, that makes the imbalance... Thanks :)

Comment: It's not percent, it's absolute points. Think of it this way. If you only have "flexible left", think of it at actually being "fixed right". The right margin is fixed. As the width changes, the right margin stays fixed. Any adjustment is made to the flexible left margin.